# Pytesseract manga text detector

Tags: image, text, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to detect text from manga, I tried with pytesseract but it does not detect all the texts. Do you know any solution to increase the quality of detection of pytesseract on these types of images?

Exemple not detect text:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8blK.jpg

"sens !" is not detected.

Currently I'm just doing a detection without a specific setting:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="fra")
```

Comment: You can improve the results by cropping the image to its (*relevant*) subsections, and then passing the subsection separately. I.E. firstly use an algorithm to determine the text sections of the image. Then crop the text sections (as small as possible), and then pass those cropped images.

Comment: But if the issue of inaccuracy of detection exists, you could try some other OCR Api's (which offer higher text detection accuracy). [This](https://www.onlineocr.net/) site being one of the best for text extraction, so you could use the api offered by them.

Answer (score 0):

The method which consists in adapting find all the parts of a text, and to read again over the ocr works well, finally I advise to pass at the same time in black and white and in color the image.